# X/Y Coordinates to Longitude/Latitude, package for .net core app

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, coordinates, software-recommendations, latitude-longitude

I have a task to convert some incoming geo data to Longitude/Latitude. The data elements in the json are identified as xCoordinate and yCoordinate.

However, the data in my sample does not look like any geographic x/y coordinate data I've looked at online, so I have a couple questions that I could use expert help on, please forgive the lack of knowledge regarding this data, I've never worked with geo data prior.

An example from my sample dataset:

- xCoordinate: 0981829
- yCoordinate: 0197525

Couple questions:

- Do these look like valid X/Y coordinates? Online examples seem to be in decimal format.
- I need suggestions for a package to import into a .net core application which converts X/Y data to Longitude/Latitude.

Comment: Info about which part of the world this coordinates belong to would help.

Comment: The address contained in the sample data is 60 Maiden Lane, New York city

Comment: did you try NY State planes either in feet or metres

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 2):

Then projection is EPSG:3628.

How to find such info? You try your luck at https://epsg.io/ and search for New York. You get a big list of possible EPSGs and then try.

When you click one, let's say EPSG:3628 (as I did in my first try), you'll see something like:

[image]

Don't get discouraged by the text about Puerto Rico, trust the title (New York Long Island), click on the map and you will get:

[image]

Now you enter your coordinates and hit Enter, and you will get:

[image]

If you now zoom enough (by clicking on + to retain position), you will reach your destination:

[image]

Another possibility is portal ProjFinder at http://projfinder.com/, which was not successeful in this case.

Still another possiblity is Shapefile ProjectionFinder Java program for Windows, which can be obtained at https://www.egger-gis.at/automatic-projection-detection/shapefile-projectionfinder/. It actually does not need shapefile, just projected coordinates and some geography name. It lists possible CRS candidates, which you can then check at epsg.io. Program was successeful in this case, correct projection was listed as the first one.